# (Laravel 8.x) Get Data From DB and Use It Directly From Master Layout without Passing It From Parameters

Tags: laravel

## My Problem

`Framework : Laravel 8.x`

I want to call my menu from DB and use it at `layout.blade.php`, but I'm using this `layout.blade.php` as my Master Layout of my view, so it's just and extends from other view.

So, I called is this way.

**layout.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
... some codes ...

<!-- Menu Navigation Before Using DB -->
<ul>
    <li>Menu 1</li>
    <li>Menu 2</li>
    <li>Menu 3</li>
    <li>Menu 4</li>
    <li>Menu 5</li>
</ul>

<!-- Menu Navigation After Using DB -->
<ul>
@foreach ($menus as $menu)
  <li>{{ $menu->name }}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>

<!-- Body Content -->
@yield('body_content')
```

**IndexController.php**

```
public function index()
{
   return view('index_page', ['menus' => $getMenusFromDB]); //just for example
}
```

**index.blade.php**

```
@extends('layout', ['menus' => $menus])

@section('body_content')
<p>Hello World !</p>
@endsection
```

I have so many views linked  to this layout, so I can't pass a `menus` parameter like this.

### My Question

How can I use this `$menus` called from DB directly to use it at `layout.blade.php` without passing it from my extended view ?

Comment: Note: I'm newbie to use this Laravel Framework

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php**

*Pass data in all views then use simple Asterisk * character*

```
use App\Model\Menu;
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
 {
    public function boot() {
       view()->composer('*', function ($view) {
          $menu = Menu::get()->toArray();
          $view->with('menu', $menu);
     });
 }
}
```

*Pass data in specific View then use this one,*

```
view()->composer('profile', function ($view) {
  $view->with('menu', $menu);
});
```

pass all common data here and used it in the blade directly.
More Info - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views

Comment: Using this `View::composer` can I set only send to my `layout.blade.php` ? rather than to send a parameters from another view. I'm sorry, I still now know about view composer

Comment: check update the answers and also you can make the common method and then call in the main blade.

Comment: Solved using this, I only share to layout so i used `View::composer('layout')` not `*`

Answer (score 1):

:) You're in luck! Laravel has a pre-built feature to share data with all views. Do check out their [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views)!

For example:

**App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function boot()
    {
        
        // Just do it like how you would normally pass data with view helpers
        View::share('$menus', '$menuFromDB');
    }
}
```

**layout.blade.php**

```
<ul>
@foreach ($menus as $menu)
  <li>{{ $menu->name }}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, i'm sorry but may I ask a last question ? I dont know about "normally pass data with view helpers" meant. I'm new in laravel :(

Comment: Ah sure! `return view('greeting', ['name' => '$name']);` 
Where "name" is the variable used in blade, and "$name" is any data from the controller. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views