# How to invoke controller methods in construct method in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I'm trying to invoke multiple methods in `__construct` function of laravel controller so that all page partials can get their data before loading the whole page. Here is some code demonstration.

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/','HomeController@index');
```

**HomeController.php**

```
class HomeController extends controller
{ 
  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->middleware("auth");
    $this->featuredNews();
  }

  public function index()
  {
     return view('pages.home');
  }

  public function featuredNews()
  {
     $news = News::select('id', 'heading', 'body', 'category', 'image', 'created_at', 'featured')->where('featured', 1)->first();
     return view('pages.home_partials.featured_news')->with('news', $news);
  }
}
```

**home.blade.php**

```
@include("pages.home_partials.featured_news");
```

Here I'm expecting the the `home.blade.php` data along with the `featured_news.blade.php` partial's data. But this code throwing an error

```
ErrorException
Undefined variable: news (View: D:\portal\resources\views\pages\home_partials\featured_news.blade.php)
```

How can I add multiple partials data along with the blade data in Laravel ?

*Laravel version: 7.30*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67783719/laravel-8-x-get-data-from-db-and-use-it-directly-from-master-layout-without-pa/67784209#67784209 ,you want to pass data in all blade?

Comment: nope. For instance, I just want to pass data into a single blade or a single web page. But I want of split it into various sub-template & render those sub templates data from different controller, and finally include all of them into the parent blade file. The above example shows to pass data in all blade, which won't be efficient for my case I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the controller property for this instead of set the view into the methods so please find the below codes which help:

**HomeController.php**

```
class HomeController extends controller
{ 
 private $news = []; 
 public function __construct()
 {
  $this->middleware("auth");
  $this->featuredNews();
 }

 public function index()
 {
   return view('pages.home')->with('news', $this->news);
 }

 public function featuredNews()
 {
   $this->news = News::select('id', 'heading', 'body', 'category', 'image', 'created_at', 'featured')->where('featured', 1)->first();
 }
}
```

Comment: well, it's returning the $news to `home.blade.php`, but I can I access this data in `featured_news.blade.php` ? Plase note that, `home.blade.php` is the parent blade file with lot of sub component(!) like `feature.blade.php`

Comment: Yes, you can access it in subview as well if you use the @inlcude directive.